# How to sort a table by ASC or DESC date?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

```
    <?php $session=$this->session->userdata['id'];
    ?>
        <?php
          foreach ($results as $r) {
            $InitDt = date(('d/m/Y'),strtotime($r->InitDt));
            $EndDt = date(('d/m/Y'),strtotime($r->EndDt));
            if($session=='1'){
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td>'.$r->idOs.'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$r->ClientName.'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$InitDt.'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$EndDt.'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$r->status.'</td>';
            echo  '</td>';
            echo '</tr>';
        }
        else
        {   
            if($session==$r->userId){
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td>'.$r->idOs.'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$r->ClientName.'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$InitDt.'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$EndDt.'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$r->status.'</td>';
            echo '<td>';
            echo '</td>';
            echo '</tr>';
        }
        }
        }
        ?>
```

This code is the call to build the table in the codeigniter view folder.
Other code controls the query to the database. There are no errors in this code. The question is only if it is possible to sort in PHP (and how to do it) or if I should use java script or similar.

[example of the code result above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xCDO.png)

Comment: where is your database query?

Comment: in another file inside the controlllers folder in the codeigniter structure. In the example above this code is in the views folder

Comment: i mean include your database query in your question

Comment: we cant help you without enough information.

Comment: @Kaneko show us your database code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
   $('#table_name').DataTable( {
       "order": [[ 3, "desc" ]]
   } );
```

} );

You Can use Datatable for sorting option. Try above code by relapsing your column index number.

For More info reffer : - https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/table_sorting.html

Answer (score 0):

Here, you can sort data in two way.

1. You can sort date using filter options such as ajax call and apply php query using of **order by** cause as per your requirement and get response in json format and re-draw table data again.
2. Otherwise you can use bootstrap data-table and apply sorting functionality on date column.

link is here for data-table : https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap4

In data-table sorting is applied by default for all column. To remove default sorting and apply sorting on particular column as below

```
var table;
jQuery(document).ready(function () { 
    table = jQuery('#cstm_people_range_list').DataTable({
            "order": [[0,"asc"]],
            "columnDefs": [{ "orderable": false, "targets": "_all" } ]
    });
});
```

Output is here. You can see that sorting functionality apply only first column.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/84iXr.png)